# How to build a dict.keys from a 2d array( which is converted from a 3d array) and a pd.read_excel(file)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have converted a 3d array: 10*600*12 to a 2d array: 10*7200, want to save it as new 'TrainData', and then concatenate it with another 10*12 excel file ('Target': 10*6, 'TargetName':10*6). I know np.concatenate and dict(zip()), but the Index is always wrong, anyone has any ideas?
I have tried first to save the new 'TrainData', and then read it with pandas, but the index becomes 9*7200.

```
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_files = glob.glob('Beispiel/*.csv')
last_df = None
alist = []
for files in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(files)
    alist.append(df)
data = np.stack(alist)
print(np.shape(data))

x = np.transpose(data).reshape(10, -1)
print(np.shape(x))
np.savetxt("Beispiel/Input.csv", x, delimiter=',', header='')

y = pd.read_excel('Prozessstoerung3/Beispiel.xlsm', sheetname=0)
print(y.head(3))
print(y.shape)
```

results

```
(10, 600, 12)
(10, 7200)
Target  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  \
0       0           1           0           0           1           1   
1       0           1           1           1           1           1   
2       0           1           0           1           0           0    

TargetName Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8 Unnamed: 9 Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 11  
0       None       Temp       None       None      Modul4      Modul5  
1       None       Temp     Modul1     Modul3      Modul4      Modul5  
2       None       Temp       None     Modul3        None        None  

(10, 12)
```

some tries:

```
TrainData = pd.concat([x, y.values[:,5]], axis=1, sort=False)
print(TrainData)
```

and results:TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

my aim is to build a dict.keys, like

```
dict_keys[('TranData'      'Target'     'TargetName')]
           array(10*7200)  array(10*6)   array(10*6)
```

Problem is solved,  because numpy array can not direct handle with pandas.
solution belows:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(x)
Name_of_data = ['Input', 'Target', 'TargetName']
new_data = dict(zip(Name_of_data, [new_df, y.values[:,0:5], y.values[:,6:11]]))
```

Comment: Can you show the `np.concatenate` command you tried. It's not quite clear to me, what you are trying to achieve -- a 10x7212 array?

Comment: yeah, i have adjusted it.